# zedgraph EnableWheelZoom, how to get axis values after zooming?

Tags: vb.net, zedgraph

In my vb.net project, I use zedgraph to draw figures. I find that the following properties work well to zoom figure on the center of mouse.

```
    Friend WithEvents gcMain As ZedGraph.ZedGraphControl
    Me.gcMain.IsZoomOnMouseCenter = True
    Me.gcMain.IsEnableWheelZoom = True
```

I have two toolstrip text boxes to show the minimum and maximum values of x axis. When I change values in text boxes, the x axis changes. The following code shows an example of handling the textbox. **However I do not know how to update values in text boxes when the figure is zoomed by using IsEnableWheelZoom** property. In zedgraph, ZedGraphControl_MouseWheel is a protected event.

```
 Friend WithEvents tbxRangeStart As System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripTextBox
     Private Sub tbxRangeStart_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles tbxRangeStart.KeyDown
    Try
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
            ' Change x Axis here
        End If
    Catch
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `ZoomEvent`:

```
chart.ZoomEvent += chart_ZoomEvent
...
private void chart_ZoomEvent(ZedGraphControl sender, ZoomState oldState, ZoomState newState)
{
    textBoxMax.Text = chart.GraphPane.XAxis.Scale.Max.ToString();
    textBoxMin.Text = chart.GraphPane.XAxis.Scale.Min.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In vb.net, use following code

```
Private Sub gcMain_ZoomEvent(ByVal sender As ZedGraphControl, ByVal oldState As ZoomState, ByVal newState As ZoomState) Handles gcMain.ZoomEvent

'update text box here    
End Sub
```